# GNUPLOT: How to set the paper auto-sized while keeping the aspect ratio correct?

Tags: c++, gnuplot

I am using C++ to stream Gnuplot scripts. But I find it is very annoying in handling aspect ratio and paper size. Does anyone has a good method to:

(1) Keep the aspect ratio correct, length 1 is 1, 2 is 2 in plot. I found the aspect ratio is dependent on the paper size!!!

(2) Zero margin paper, the paper size would be autoscaled. I found eps figure always has big margins.

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color font 'Helvetica,2000' size 640,480
set output 'grid.eps'
set size 1, 1
set hidden3d
unset key
unset tics
unset border
set view 0,0,1,1
set xrange [0:3]
set yrange [0:6]
set zrange [0:1]
set title 'grid test'
splot 'grid.dat' using 1:2:3 with lines lt 2 lc rgb '#100000'
```

`grid.dat` file:

```
0 0 0
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0

0 2 0
1 2 0
2 2 0
3 2 0

0 4 0
1 4 0
2 4 0
3 4 0

0 6 0
1 6 0
2 6 0
3 6 0
```

By saying aspect ratio correct, I mean I want the plot to look like exactly a 2:1 rectangular grid, not like square or anything else. I don't want the figure to be stretched someway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the trick, suppose we have the following generic script:

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color font 'Helvetica,20' size Lx,Ly
set xrange [XMIN:XMAX]
set yrange [YMIN:YMAX]
```

First, set XMIN and XMAX and YMIN and YMAX to the min and max of the plots.

Then, set `Lx`, say let `Lx = 100`, then `Ly` should be set as `floor(100*(YMAX-YMIN)/(XMAX-XMIN)))`.

After this one could use some shell script to do the margin removal.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to set the aspect ratio of your plot.  To do that, you want to use something like:

```
set size ratio ASPECT_RATIO
```

this will make it so that the length of the y-axis divided by the length of the x-axis (in graph units) is `ASPECT_RATIO`.  If you want the ratio to be determined in plot units, then you would use a negative number for `ASPECT_RATIO`.